# How to track asynchronous scripts (that do not provide a callback)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, tracking

We are testing a new kind of advertising method that does call scripts asynchronously but they DO NOT provide a callback for anything.  We want to track the loading time of this new method after it has finished loading and written new elements into a div or something.

Is the only way to do this to looking for a change in the number of children of this specific element via setTimetout()?  What other do I have to do this?

I missed an existing Stack Overflow answer to this question, I apologize in advance.

Comment: `document.body.onchange()`? (Or generally, `onchange` for the element in question)... may not be supported everywhere, or even work at all

Comment: Just tested and it certainly doesn't work in IE or FF, so that makes it useless even if it works anywhere else...

Comment: @DaveRandom: hm, but nice idea anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there is an onload event for the script, and also an onreadystatechange event. IE uses the readystate event, others use onload. See article for details.

http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
script.onreadystatechange= function () {
  if (this.readyState == 'complete') complete();
}
script.onload= complete;
script.src = 'some.js';
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the advert loads another script, but will give that a try!